# Delphi DLL comport

Tags: delphi, dll, serial-port, delphi-2010

i am developing a DLL in Delphi 2010 that is communicating with Comport.

But there is a problem that ia dont get any value from the port.
i am using the RxChar but i think the com objet is not triggering the RxChar command.

how can i trigger the RxChar so it would work??

```
unit unitfxvogir;

{$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF}

interface

uses
  ComObj, ActiveX, AxCtrls, Classes,
  ridFXVogir_TLB, StdVcl, CPort, CPortCtl, ExtCtrls;

type
  Tfxvogir = class(TAutoObject, IConnectionPointContainer, Ifxvogir)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FConnectionPoints: TConnectionPoints;
    FConnectionPoint: TConnectionPoint;
    FEvents: IfxvogirEvents;
    { note: FEvents maintains a *single* event sink. For access to more
      than one event sink, use FConnectionPoint.SinkList, and iterate
      through the list of sinks. }
    ComPort1: TComPort;
  public
    procedure Initialize; override;
    procedure AfterConstruction; override;
    procedure BeforeDestruction; override;
    procedure ComPort1RxChar(Sender: TObject; Count: Integer); safecall;
  protected
    function OpnaVog(const ComPort: WideString): WordBool; safecall;
    function LokaVog: WordBool; safecall;
    function Vigt: WideString; safecall;
    { Protected declarations }
    function SendaSkipun(const Inntak: WideString): WordBool; safecall;
    property ConnectionPoints: TConnectionPoints read FConnectionPoints
      implements IConnectionPointContainer;
    procedure EventSinkChanged(const EventSink: IUnknown); override;
  end;

implementation

uses ComServ, unitAdgerdir;

procedure Tfxvogir.EventSinkChanged(const EventSink: IUnknown);
begin
  FEvents := EventSink as IfxvogirEvents;
end;

procedure Tfxvogir.Initialize;
begin
  inherited Initialize;
  FConnectionPoints := TConnectionPoints.Create(Self);
  if AutoFactory.EventTypeInfo <> nil then
    FConnectionPoint := FConnectionPoints.CreateConnectionPoint(
      AutoFactory.EventIID, ckSingle, EventConnect)
  else FConnectionPoint := nil;
end;

procedure Tfxvogir.AfterConstruction;
begin
  inherited;
  ComPort1 := TComPort.Create(ComPort1);
  //tmrtimer := TTimer.Create(ComPort1);
end;

procedure Tfxvogir.BeforeDestruction;
begin
  inherited;
  ComPort1.Free;
  //tmrtimer.Free;
end;

function Tfxvogir.OpnaVog(const ComPort: WideString): WordBool;
begin
 try
  //tmrtimer.Enabled := false;
  //tmrtimer.Interval := 100;

  ComPort1.Port                     := ComPort;
  ComPort1.BaudRate                 := br2400;
  ComPort1.DataBits                 := dbSeven;
  ComPort1.StopBits                 := sbOneStopBit;
  ComPort1.Parity.Bits              := prEven;
  ComPort1.FlowControl.FlowControl  := fcNone;

  if not ComPort1.Connected then
    ComPort1.Open;

  if ComPort1.Connected then
    Result := True;

  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;

function Tfxvogir.LokaVog: WordBool;
begin
  try
    if ComPort1.Connected then
      ComPort1.Close;

    Result := True;
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;

function Tfxvogir.Vigt: WideString;
begin
  Result := g_rVigtun.VigtunGr;
end;

procedure Tfxvogir.ComPort1RxChar(Sender: TObject; Count: Integer);
var
  Str: string;
  str1 : ansichar;
    i : Integer;
  cStafur : AnsiChar;
begin
  ComPort1.Readstr(Str, Count);
  try
    for i := 1 to count do begin
      cStafur := AnsiChar(str[i]);
      LesaSvar(cStafur);
    end;

  except
    g_rVigtun.SvarTexti := 'Villa í tengingu';
  end;
end;

function Tfxvogir.SendaSkipun(const Inntak: WideString): WordBool;
var
  //I : Integer;
  BCC : Integer;
  sCommand : AnsiString;
begin
  //ATH höndla ef slökkt er á vog = ekkert svar berst
  Result := False;
  g_rVigtun := FrumstillaVigtun;

  if Length(Inntak) < 1 then begin
    g_rVigtun.SvarTexti := 'VILLA: Engin skipun til að senda.';
    exit(false);
  end;

  //Er þetta lögleg skipun    if (rSending.Kaupsamn <> '') and (rSending.Kaupsamn[1] in ['K', 'V']) then begin
  if not (Inntak[1] in ['C','G','M','O','R','T','W','Z']) then begin
    g_rVigtun.SvarTexti := 'VILLA: ['+Inntak+'] er óþekkt skipun.';
    exit(false);
  end;

  g_rVigtun.Skipun := ansichar(Inntak[1]);
  SamskiptiByrja;
  g_StoduVel := svNyttSvar;

  BCC := ReiknaBCC(Inntak);
  //Skipun er alltaf á forminu
  //<STX><[SKIPUN][aukatexti]><ETX><BCC>
  sCommand := STX + Inntak + ETX + Chr(BCC);

  //ATH ætti að hreinsa inntaks buffer hér ?
  try
    ComPort1.WriteStr(sCommand);
  except

  end;
  Result := True;
end;

initialization
  TAutoObjectFactory.Create(ComServer, Tfxvogir, Class_fxvogir,
    ciMultiInstance, tmApartment);
end.
```

Comment: Where did you set com **Timeout constants**? Why DLL, why not to do first Uint and than DLL?

Answer (score 2):

```
 ComPort1.FlowControl.FlowControl  := fcNone;
```

That's okay on modern machines, especially with a baudrate of 2400, but now it is up to you to control the handshake lines.  You have to turn the DTR and RTS signals on so the device knows that you're online and ready to receive data.